# Two subdomains, two iredmail (postfix) servers, duplication and migration

Tags: postfix, mikrotik, iredmail

There are two servers in the local network, and iredmail is installed on both (I don't think this is important, since Postfix is here). There is one domain example.com and one IP, and also two subdomains here: `servermail.example.com` and `mail.example.com`. There is a Mikrotik router in front of them, which holds a local network and communicates with the world.

Roughly speaking, explicitly specify the server, but at the same time there is one user everywhere. For example on mail.example.com and on servermail.example.com there is one user user1234@example.com and he can send and receive emails to two servers at the same time. Is it possible to use duplicate emails for this? Or is it possible to set up something like postfix relay, which will understand who the email was assigned to? That is, to which server, servermail.example.com or mail.example.com.

Comment: Yes you can send an email to multiple addresses. Yes you can configure most MTAs to replicate emails to designated destination. But I suspect you are trying to ask something else which you've not explained clearly. And I have no idea what the router has to do with this.

Comment: @symcbean ,In short, the old server mail.example.com he is dying and his problem is in VERY old hardware and software. Therefore, I want to raise the second server, manually add users there and transfer emails via imapsync and turn off the old server, and the mail continued to function and work with the domain example.com , only so that the company's customers and employees notice little.

Comment: seems a very strange way to migrate the server. Just do a straight swap. Switch off (orblock) the SMTP server, copy the config, data and, if necessary, the IP address.

Comment: @symcbean ,The problem is the big difference in the versions of iRedMail. I have already tried this method and it cannot be done this way, because the server does not start. Their website indicates how to make a transfer / update, but there are too many problems and too long a transfer is expected, as well as there is a chance of damaging the database and other data.

Comment: So you're going to magically make the new server behave as expected without configuring it?

Comment: @symcbean , Very funny. I asked how to configure this park, and you write about the "magic way".